# How to show $q:H_2(S^1\times S^1)\longrightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1, S^1\vee S^1)$ is an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to solve exercise 2.2.12 in Hatcher's algebraic topology book.

**Exercise:** Show that the quotient map $S^1\times S^1\longrightarrow S^2$ collapsing $S^1\vee S^1$ to a point is not nullhomotopic showing it induces an isomorphism in $H_2$.

**Partial Solution:** Since $(S^1\times S^1, S^1\vee S^1)$ is a good pair we have $$H_2(S^1\times S^1, S^1\vee S^1)\simeq H_2\left(S^1\times S^1/S^1\vee S^1\right)=H_2(S^2).$$ Then we have $q_*:H_2(S^1\times S^1)\longrightarrow (S^1\times S^1, S^1\vee S^1)$. Consider the long exact sequence of the pair $(S^1\times S^1, S^1\vee S^1)$:$$0\longrightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1)\longrightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1, S^1\vee S^1)\longrightarrow H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\longrightarrow H_1(S^1\times S^1).$$ I saw somewhere $H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\longrightarrow H_1(S^1\times S^1)$ is an isomorphism, but I can't see why. Hence $q_*$ is an isomorphism so that it can be nullhomotopic for if that was the case $q_*=0$.

**Doubt:** How to explain why $H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\longrightarrow H_1(S^1\times S^1)$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 4):

By your exact sequence you already have exactness of $$0 \rightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1) \rightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1, S^1 \vee S^1) \rightarrow H_1(S^1 \vee S^1).$$
Now by your computation, the first two of these groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. Thus $q^\ast$ is multiplication by $d$ for some integer $d$, and the map $$\rightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1, S^1 \vee S^1) \rightarrow H_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$$ has kernel $d\mathbb Z$, but since $H_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ is free abelian, this is only possible for $d=\pm 1$ (why?) which proves that $q^\ast$ is an isomorphism (why?)

Comment: @PtF: Unless you have some issue with this post, you should select this as the answer.

Comment: I don't quite get how I can conclude that $d=1 $ or $d=-1$ using that $H_1$ is free abelian ?

Comment: @Simonsays If $d$ is neither $+-1$, then by the first isomorphism theorem $H_1(S^1 ∨S^1)$ must have a nonzero finite subgroup which is impossible.